Size problem in QGIS clustering
I've configured cluster symbols for point features, utilizing the "Assistant" sizing method linked to a specific attribute. However, when multiple features form a cluster, the symbol size is calculated based on a single feature's attribute value. The desired behavior is to calculate the sum of the attribute values for all features within the cluster and use this sum to determine the symbol size.
How can I accomplish this?
